# (node:17891) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: newPay.save is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

the console is logging the user but whenever i add the save method i get the error above, any help will be nice`enter code here`
this is my controller;

```
 paymentPost: async(req, res, err)=>{
   let {plan, amount, payID} = req.body
   let userID = req.body
   userID = payID
   if(!payID || !plan || !amount){
    res.json({
      message: "all field required"
    })
   } else{
  await User.findOne({userID}).then(async(userId)=>{
     if(!userId || userID.length<9){
       res.status(400).json({
        message: "No user with this ID",
       })
     }else 
      await Payment.findOne({},async (err, payer)=>{
        if(!payer){
            let newPay = []
            newPay.push(new Payment({
            payID,
            amount,
            plan,
            status:true
      }))
      console.log(newPay)
      return newPay.save()
      .then(res.status(200).json({
        message: "Payment successfull",
        newPay
      }))
       }
     
   })
  }
 },
```

i just need the user to save to database

Comment: Fix your indentation. This code is missing braces on `if/else` statements. You should also update your question to include any errors that are being thrown, and the results of your debugging i.e. the `console.log`. You should include what you are actually observing when your code runs and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `callbacks` and `async` on the same function call.
You are also referencing the array `newPay` which is going to be scoped to the callback function only, and the array does not have a function called `save`.

Modify your implementation to something similar to below.

```
 const userId = await User.findOne({userID})
 if(!userId || userID.length<9) {
     return res.status(400).json({ message: "No user with this ID" });
 } else {
     const payer = await Payment.findOne({});
     if(!payer) {
        let payee = new Payment({ payID, amount, plan, status:true });
        await payee.save();
        return res.json({ message: "Payment successfull", newPay });
     }
     return res.json({ message: '?' }); // you also need to send a response here if not payer is found
 }
```

If you want to push the `Payment` instance to an array for retrieval in subsequent calls, just add the push after you have created the instance.

```
     if(!payer) {
        let payee = new Payment({ payID, amount, plan, status:true });
        await payee.save();
        payees.push(payee);
        return res.json({ message: "Payment successfull", newPay });
     }
```

The array will have to be from an outer context. i.e. in your implementation the array `newPay` is scoped to the `Payment.findOne` callback function.

So outside of your `paymentPost` function (but somewhere in scope of the function that will need to lookup the array), you will need to define the array. For example

```
//payees array is in scope of both paymentPost and paymentGet
const payees = [];
module.exports = {
     paymentPost: async () => {
         // implementation
         payees.push(payee);
     },

     paymentGet: async (id) => {
         return payees.find(payee => payee.payID === id);
     }
}
```

Comment: yes, i already got it to work this way, but what i really want to achieve is to save each unique payer's payment  in his/her own newPay array, so i can query each user's payment history if i want to

Comment: @MSadiq - Update your question - that is not what you are asking `"i just need the user to save to database"`

Comment: sure i want the user(newPay) saved but inside its own array, sorry if my initial question wasn't clear, i'm still kind of new to this